# Mysql query to filter out data based on two logic

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a sample table:

```
  sample_id  |      timestamp       | p_id
============================================
    62054    |  2018-09-25 10:18:15 |  2652
    62054    |  2018-09-27 16:44:57 |  966
    62046    |  null                |  1809
    62046    |  2018-09-25 10:18:15 |  2097
```

We need to filter out unique sample_id column, but the logic is

1. IF the timestamp column **is null**, then return those null column data

   ```
       62046 | null | 1809
   ```
2. IF the timestamp column **is not null**, then return the latest timestamp column data

   ```
    62054 | 2018-09-27 16:44:57 | 966
   ```

So its great if anyone provide the sql query.

We need somethings like that,

```
WHERE
IF(
    NOT NULL = all row group by sample_id,
    row where cancelled_at is maximum,
    null column
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query should give you the results you want. It looks for a row with a `NULL` timestamp, or a row which has a `non-NULL` timestamp which is the maximum timestamp for that sample_id, but only if there isn't a row for that sample_id which has a `NULL` timestamp:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
WHERE timestamp IS NULL OR
      timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) 
                   FROM table1 t2 
                   WHERE t2.sample_id = t1.sample_id) AND
                   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                               FROM table1 t3
                               WHERE t3.sample_id = t1.sample_id AND
                                     t3.timestamp IS NULL)
```

Output:

```
sample_id   timestamp               p_id
62054       2018-09-27T16:44:57Z    966
62046       (null)                  1809
```

Answer (score 1):

Using variables:

```
SELECT sample_id, timestamp, p_id
FROM (
   SELECT sample_id, timestamp, p_id,
          @seq := IF(@s_id = sample_id, @seq + 1,
                     IF(@s_id := sample_id, 1, 1)) AS seq
   FROM mytable
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @s_id := 0, @seq := 0) AS vars
   ORDER BY 
      sample_id,
      CASE 
         WHEN timestamp IS NULL THEN 1
         ELSE 2
      END,
      timestamp DESC
) AS t
WHERE t.seq = 1;
```

[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/NXYVM58953)

**Explanation:**

To understand how this works you need to execute the subquery and examine the output it produces:

```
SELECT sample_id, timestamp, p_id,
       @seq := IF(@s_id = sample_id, @seq + 1,
                  IF(@s_id := sample_id, 1, 1)) AS seq
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @s_id := 0, @seq := 0) AS vars
ORDER BY 
   sample_id,
   CASE 
      WHEN timestamp IS NULL THEN 1
      ELSE 2
   END,
   timestamp DESC
```

**Output:**

```
sample_id   timestamp           p_id    seq
-------------------------------------------
62046       NULL                1809    1
62046       25.09.2018 10:18:15 2097    2
62054       27.09.2018 16:44:57 966     1
62054       25.09.2018 10:18:15 2652    2
```

You can see here that calculated field `seq` is used to prioritize records inside each `sample_id` slice.

**Note:** If you're on MySQL 8.0 you can use window functions to implement the same logic.

Comment: Thanks you sir for your answer. But may be their is a problem. In second condition, 
IF the timestamp column is not null, then return the latest timestamp column data
**62054 | 2018-09-27 16:44:57 | 966**
we need this data.

But query return this,
**62054 | 25.09.2018 10:18:15 | 2652**

Answer (score 1):

Find out those records where time is not null and filter out
   timestamp nulls sample_id and for null timestamp
 Use union

```
select * from t1 where (t1.sample_id,t1.timestamp)
in (

SELECT t.sample_id,max(t.timestamp) AS time
   FROM t1 t
   WHERE t.sample_id NOT IN (select sample_id from t1 where t1.timestamp is null)
     GROUP BY t.sample_id
 )
 UNION
SELECT *
   FROM t1 t 
 WHERE t.timestamp IS NULL

output
    sample_id   timestamp           p_id
    62054       2018-09-27 16:44:57 966
    62046       null                1809
```

Answer (score 0):

- Group by on the `sample_id`.
- Using [If()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function, check if the [minimum value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) of the timestamp for the group is `null` or not. If it is `null`, return `null`, else return the [Max()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) value.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT sample_id, 
       IF(MIN(timestamp) IS NULL, 
          NULL, 
          MAX(timestamp)) AS timestamp 
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY sample_id
```

Comment: thanks your answer. But we need to filter out those data (Not on select, need it on where clause). And need the full row data. For your visualization we update the question.